# PHP MYSQL Check & Append Function

Tags: php, mysql, function, append

I hope someone can help. Basically I'm fairly OK with PHP and MySQL,
however, I need some advice on how to complete this task.

As my system is to complex to explain, I've condensed it down so it's clearer.

Basically, I have an simple PHP Form that asks the user for their:
Name,Item Ordered, Item Quantity. The OrderID is autogenerated and is a random
4 number. So at the moment I do it with this:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO system_orders
 (orderid,name,itemordered,itemquantity)  VALUES
 ('$randomgeneratednumber', '$_POST[name]','$_POST[itemordered]','$_POST[itemquantity]')"; and
 run $sql
```

Now what I want is if they put the quantity as "2", I want it to create an additional row and append
the randomgeneratednumber. For example, if the randomgeneratednumber was 9876 and the quantity was 2, it would create an additional new row, with the $randomgeneratednumber-2, in this example 9876-2

Would anyone know how to achieve this?

I have temporarily used an if statement (which I know is really bad programming practice)
to append the -2 manually, but there must be a function out there to detect if $quantity = 2
then create additional row with the appended -2 and so on for 3,4,5,6,7,8...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using auto-increment for the orderid?

Comment: Yes, basically the OrderID is a trackable link on another system, I don't want to use auto-increment because people can easily guess an order number and see the details, so the autogeneratednumber prevents this (well gives them less chance to guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
if ($quantity > 1) {
    for ($q = 2; $q <= $quantity; $q++) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO system_orders
                (orderid,name,itemordered,itemquantity)  VALUES
                ('$randomgeneratednumber-$q', '$_POST[name]',  '$_POST[itemordered]', '$_POST[itemquantity]')";
       // run $sql
    }
}
```

You also should switch to a database API that supports parametrized queries, or escape the user-supplied inputs.

Comment: from the question I don't think he wants one row for each incremental item quantity just an additional single entry for the multiple items ie one base row and a max of one additional row with the quantity as an additional string on the order number. at least thats how I read his question

Comment: I guess we'll find out when he decides which of our answers to accept.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answers, I'm trying this piece of code, however, on this line 'for (var $q = 2; $q <= $quantity; $q++) {' is reporting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR, expecting ';

Comment: Sorry, a little Javascript creeped in there.

Comment: Hello, after extensive testing, It's still not working. For example, say the quantity was set to 3, this code should have created 3 seperate MySQL rows ? I'm only getting one row that's created.

Comment: After Tweaking with the code you have given, finally managed to fix it, your code worked! Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO system_orders
 (orderid,name,itemordered,itemquantity)  VALUES
 ('$randomgeneratednumber', '$_POST[name]','$_POST[itemordered]','$_POST[itemquantity]')"; and
 run $sql

if ($_POST['itemquantity']>1) {
$multipleorderid = $randomgeneratednumber."-".$POST['itemquantity'];
 $sql="INSERT INTO system_orders
 (orderid,name,itemordered,itemquantity)  VALUES
 ('$multipleorderid', '$_POST[name]','$_POST[itemordered]','$_POST[itemquantity]')"; and
 run $sql
}
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks very much for your code you have provided. This is similar to what I had done at the start, the issue is, what happens if the item quantity is 3? this will create the first sql row and then create another row with $randomgeneratednumber-3 but what about $randomgeneratednumber-2 ? - I need it to create a separate row for each quantity value. i.e. quantity 20, creates 20 rows..